# Returning multiple 2d arrays in C with row and column number to be input from a file in main

Tags: c

Help me guys... It's for a really important project
I want to return multiple 2d arrays in C with row and column number to be input from a file in main, so they are basically unknown.
All I basically have to do is to use some matrices in main which were manipulated in other function.
So if you know of some way like using those 2d arrays in main using returning of multiple matrices or structure or pointers or global declaration, help me out..!
The dimensions are input from a txt file so they can be changed.

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do it. Write the code? Please, this isn't a "do my project" site.

Comment: We are neither a coding nor a tutoring service. And your question is also unclear.

Comment: You need to provide some code so we can understand your problem. Read about what is meant by a [MCVE]. Are you sure that you need your function to _return_ arrays? Why not just manipulate the arrays through pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create what is effectively a 2D array by allocating an array of pointers, then an array for each of those pointers.

For example:

```
int **get2darray(int rows, int cols)
{
    int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
    if (!matrix) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<cols; i++) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
        if (!matrix[i]) {
            perror("malloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Not very effective for a 2D array, not being contiguous storage:(